# Aspect Fit and Aspect Fill content mode with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I need to add two new content modes to display my textures with OpenGL ES 2.0 : "Aspect Fit" and "Aspect Fill'.

Here's an image explaining the different content modes :

[image]

I already have the "Scale to fill" content mode, which is the default behavior I guess.

Here's my basic vertex shader code for textures :

```
precision highp float;

attribute vec2 aTexCoordinate;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    vTexCoordinate = aTexCoordinate;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

And here's my fragment shader for textures :

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec4 vColor;
uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;

void main() {
    // premultiplied alpha
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);
    // Scale the texture RGB by the vertex color
    texColor.rgb *= vColor.rgb;
    // Scale the texture RGBA by the vertex alpha to reinstate premultiplication
    gl_FragColor = texColor * vColor.a;
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

For the "Aspect Fill" mode, I thought I could play with the texture coordinates to crop the image. But for the "Aspect Fit" mode, I don't have a clear idea on how I could do it in the shaders, and even better with a red background color like in the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Rabbid76 and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62821532/5120292) , I managed to do it after adding this part to his answer :

```
float textureAspect = (float)textureSize.width / (float)textureSize.height;
float frameAspect = (float)frameSize.width / (float)frameSize.height;

float scaleX = 1, scaleY = 1;
float textureFrameRatio = textureAspect / frameAspect;
BOOL portraitTexture = textureAspect < 1;
BOOL portraitFrame = frameAspect < 1;

if(contentMode == AspectFill) {
    if(portraitFrame)
        scaleX = 1.f / textureFrameRatio;
    else
        scaleY = textureFrameRatio;
}
else if(contentMode == AspectFit) {
    if(portraitFrame)
        scaleY = textureFrameRatio;
    else
        scaleX = 1.f / textureFrameRatio;
}
```

Then I do `vec2(scaleX, scaleY)`

Answer (score 8):

You have to scale the texture coordinates. I recommend to add a uniform for scaling the texture:

```c
uniform vec2 textureScale;

void main()
{
    vTexCoordinate = textureScale * (aTexCoordinate - 0.5) + 0.5;
    // [...]
}
```

Compute the aspect ratio of the texture:

```
aspect = textrueHeight / textureWidth
```

The the `textureScale` has to be set dependent on the mode:

- "Scale To Fill": `vec2(1.0, 1.0)`.
- landscape "Aspect Fit": `vec2(1.0, aspect)`.
- landscape "Aspect Fill": `vec2(1.0/aspect, 1.0)`.
- portrait "Aspect Fit": `vec2(1.0/aspect, 1.0)`.
- portrait "Aspect Fill": `vec2(1.0, aspect)`.

You have to set the texture wrap parameters (`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`, `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`) mode to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).

Alternatively you can [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) superfluous fragments in the fragment shader:

```
void main() {
    if (vTexCoordinate.x < 0.0 || vTexCoordinate.x > 1.0 ||
        vTexCoordinate.y < 0.0 || vTexCoordinate.y > 1.0) {
    
        discard;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A metal fragment shader, For making a texture aspect fill/fit within an expected size.

```
fragment float4 fragment_aspect_fitfill(
                               VertexOut vertexIn [[stage_in]],
                               texture2d<float, access::sample> sourceTexture [[texture(0)]],
                               sampler sourceSampler [[sampler(0)]],
                               constant float2 &size [[ buffer(0) ]],
                               constant float &contentMode [[ buffer(1) ]])
{
    float2 uv = vertexIn.textureCoordinate;
    
    //Calculate Aspect Ration for both Texture and Expected output texture
    float textureAspect = (float)sourceTexture.get_width() / (float)sourceTexture.get_height();
    float frameAspect = (float)size.x / (float)size.y;
    
    
    float scaleX = 1, scaleY = 1;
    float textureFrameRatio = textureAspect / frameAspect;
    bool portraitTexture = textureAspect < 1;
    bool portraitFrame = frameAspect < 1;
    
    
    // Content mode 0 is for aspect Fill, 1 is for Aspect Fit
    if(contentMode == 0.0) {
        if(portraitFrame)
            scaleX = 1.f / textureFrameRatio;
        else
            scaleY = textureFrameRatio;
    } else if(contentMode == 1.0) {
        if(portraitFrame)
            scaleY = textureFrameRatio;
        else
            scaleX = 1.f / textureFrameRatio;
    }
    
    float2 textureScale = float2(scaleX, scaleY);
    float2 vTexCoordinate = textureScale * (uv - 0.5) + 0.5;
    

    return sourceTexture.sample(sourceSampler, vTexCoordinate);
}
```

** Note: Use `MetalPetal` for better understanding some struct like `VertexOut` etc.

** This fragment shader **algorithm may not be perfect**, but this works and **worked for me**.